# Merge array with the same keys, array_merge doesn't work fine

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have arrays with the same key like this:

```
Array1(
    [00] => green
    [10] => red
    [20] => yellow
)

Array2(
    [00] => avocado
    [10] => apple
    [20] => banana
)
```

I want this:

```
Array_result(
    [00] => Array(
            [0] => green
            [1] => avocado
        )

    [10] => Array(
            [0] => red
            [1] => apple
        )

    [20] => Array(
            [0] => yellow
            [1] => banana
        ))
```

Or [0], [1], [2], I do not mind the key, I try array_merge but it doesn't work fine.

EDIT: I don't know why, but array_merge_recursive prints this:

```
Array
(
    [00] => Array
        (
            [0] => green
            [1] => avocado
        )

    [0] => red
    [1] => apple
    [2] => yellow
    [3] => banana
)
```

Comment: This is actually a pretty good question, +1.

Comment: @Pachonk You think so? When it could have been solved easily by [typing it into Google](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313542/merge-array-with-the-same-keys-array-merge-doesnt-work-fine#comment21617935_15313596) instead of SO?

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig, SO's goal is to create huge libraries of questions, regardless... This question is nicely worded, may be easy to find... But this is the best worded question out of the questions similar to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`array_merge_recursive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) instead of `array_merge`.

```
<?php
$A = Array(00 => "green", 10 => "red", 20 => "yellow");
$B = Array(00 => "avocado", 10 => "apple", 20 => "banana");

$result = array_merge_recursive($A, $B);

print_r($result);?>
```

[See it in action](http://ideone.com/Oewrb).

Comment: Nice catch. Never stumbled upon this function. PHP really has a function for everything...insane.

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig, found this by typing the question into google... Big surprise :D

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
function merge($arr){
$n = array();
if(!empty($arr)){
foreach($arr as $a){
if(!empty($a)){
foreach($a as $k => $v){
$n[$k][] = $v;
}}}}
return $n;
}

// use
$a = array('00' => 'green', '10' => 'red', '20' => 'yellow');
$b = array('00' => 'avocado', '10' => 'apple', '20' => 'apple');
print_r(merge(array($a, $b)));
```

Comment: this solution for me working nice